# Install Puppet 5.5.x on Ubuntu 2018

Tags: puppet, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-18.04

We have Ubuntu 2018 and would like to use [puppet-letsencrypt](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/letsencrypt).

However Ubuntu 2018 comes with Puppet 5.4, while puppet-letsencrypt requires Puppet version 5.5.8.

How am I supposed to upgrade to 5.5.x?

According to [puppet manual](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/puppet_platform.html#apt-based-systems) it should be possible with following commands:

```sh
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-bionic.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppet5-release-bionic.deb
sudo apt update
```

But, after that, Puppet is still 5.4:

```
~$ puppet --version
5.4.0
```

Any ideas how to use this certbot on Ubuntu 2018?

Comment: I think you forgot `apt upgrade`.

Comment: Adding `apt upgrade` or `apt get upgrade` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you check https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/upgrade_minor.html 
to upgrade puppet server
{# apt-get install --only-upgrade puppetserver}
to upgrade agents
{# apt-get install --only-upgrade puppet-agent}

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause and a solution.

### Root cause

Ubuntu has a package puppet, which I had installed using `apt-get install puppet`. That puppet was in the way. Puppet itself is using the `puppet-agent` package from their own repository.

### The solution

Remove the Puppet installation from Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get remove puppet
```

Install puppet as documented in the manual. Commands used:

```
sudo wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-bionic.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppet5-release-bionic.deb
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install puppet-agent -y
sudo ln -s /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet /usr/local/bin/puppet
```

After this `puppet` `5.5.22` is running in Ubuntu 18.04.